# Download files from google drive to Xamarin Android Player

Tags: android, json, xamarin, android-emulator, cocossharp

Working on a Cocossharp application under Xamarin, I test it in Xamarin Android Player.

It works but I need to upload json files from Emulator File System to my application.

I did not find solution to upload files from the pc to the emulated device (Nexus 5 Lolipop 5.1.1).

I transfered my json files to Google Drive.

I connected to Google Drive to access my files from de emulator.

I dowloaded files to the emulator.

In google drive my file name is ECG01.json

In the device, the file name become an ununderstandable file name dot bin.

When I try to open it, the emulator display an error : can't open file.

Is there a solution to transfert files unchanged to the emulated device ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `adb` or `Android Device Monitor` to copy files from your local PC's file system to your Android Emulator.

Via the device monitor you can browse the files on your emulator and use the `Push` / `Pull` icons to copy files.

[image]

This UI is automating `adb`, so you can also do it via the cmd-line with `adb`:

**Push** a file from your PC to your emulator/device:

```
adb push <LocalPcFile> <TargetPath>
```

**Pull** a file from your emulator/device:

```
adb pull <FullPathOfFileOnEmulator>
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html